# antlr4 generated files - which are required at runtime

Tags: java, antlr

I wanted to use `antlr` library for one of my projects. I browsed through available wiki pages on `antlr4` website and written my grammar.

Everything looks good but I am wondering about some of the generated files.

I have bunch of `.java` files (Lexer, Parser, Listener, BaseListener) but I also have two files with `.tokens` extension. I am wondering if they are needed by generated parser and lexer during runtime or they are just byproduct of java code generation and I do not need to include them in my project?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.tokens files are not needed at runtime. They are just used for ANTLR to share info between grammars, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the info from the source :)